# Copy and paste repeatedly a set of values one after the other for multiple times using Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of strings lets say A, B, C, D, E, F, G, etc. in my 1st row in different cells. Now I want to copy and paste A 5 times beginning with row 1 which is followed by B 5 times and then C and so on. I know there is for loop involved in that but am unable to make my way through it.  I will be grateful if someone could help me on this.

Comment: Actually I need to do it for 3500+ strings which should repeat 30 times each

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim cel As Range
Dim count As Integer
Dim CurrentCel As Range

'Find the last used column in the first row
LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
Set CurrentCel = Range("A1")

'Loop through each cell in the top row with the values in
For Each cel in Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,LastCol)).cells
    'Add the value in that cell to the list 5 times
    For count = 1 To 5
        CurrentCel.value = cel.value
        Set CurrentCel = CurrentCel.Offset(1,0)
    Next count
Next
```

Note that this will overwrite the value currently in A1, and it will only work if you have an unbroken list in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

**Without VBA**

With data in **A1** thru **G1,** in **A2** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$G$1,1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/5,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]